# Stochastic process $X(t)=W_tX(t-1)$ with $\left\{W_t\right\}_{t=1}^n$ iid row stochastic matrices

Tags: stochastic-processes, random, markov-process

I have been struggling for a while with the following problem. Consider a sequence of iid row stochastic matrices $\left\{W_t\right\}_{t=1}^n$ and the linear dynamical system $X(t)=W_tX(t-1)$ with some initial condition $X(0)=\{X_1(0),\dots,X_n(0)\} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where $X_i(0)$ are iid $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ r.v.

I am interested in showing that the following expression is increasing in time (or if it does not, at least how it behaves):
$\sum\limits_{i,j=1}^n \left\{E\left[\frac{(X_i^t-\bar{X^t})(X_j^t-\bar{X^t})}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i^t-\bar{X^t})^2}\right]^2\right\}$.

The expectation is at time $t-1$ and regarding $W^t$.

Any help would be more than welcome.

Comment: Do you know distribution of $W_t$?

Comment: You can assume to know the distribution (there is no particular restriction on what this should be). In my simulations, where I find support on the result, the way I generate the random matrices is as follows: For each row, I choose at random how many and which elements will be different than zero. Then for each of these elements I pick a number from a U(0,1), say $a_{ij}$. the value of the weight becomes $w_{ij}=\frac{a_{ij}}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^n a_{ij}}$

Comment: I asked because if you assume that distribution of $W_t$ is degenerate, then product of $W_t$'s converges and hence $X_t$ converges. When does the expression of interest come from? To me it looks like it has an extraneous square inside the main bracket.

Comment: Indeed, $X_t$ converges. My ultimate goal in this one was to show that the expression converges to 1 (or at least that it gets close to 1) before $X_t$ converges. In fact, the square is crucial there. Without it, if you bring the summation inside the expectation, the expression becomes always equal to zero (without expectation).